# Web App Returns Same Content Regardless of Request

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Using Eclipse's internal representation of Tomcat8 (do not know if that is relevant), the following is a series of page requests. This comes from the file:
C:\Users\BS\Eclipse\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs\localhost_access_log.2016-04-25.txt:

```
"GET /ProjK/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/WEFiles/Css/v02/openElement.css?v=50491098000 HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/Templates/BaseLayer.css?v=50491098000 HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/index.css?v=50491098000 HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/WEFiles/Client/jQuery/migrate.js?v=50491098000 HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/WEFiles/Client/Common/oe.min.js?v=50491098000 HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/Files/Image/Template/Top.png HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/Files/Image/Template/Logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/Files/Image/BioTransparent.png HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/WEFiles/Image/WEImage/PuceImg-3f204a74.png HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
"GET /ProjK/WEFiles/Image/empty.png HTTP/1.1" 200 16354
```

Observe that each response is the same byte count. The browser receives the content of the same file regardless of the request.

The content is from "index.html" that has been renamed to "index.ftl" and renamed back to "index.html". I have been making simple edits to this file hoping to see any change in what the browser shows.

I see that the file "index.html" has been updated with the new content in both the workspace and the /tmp0/webapps/ folder.

Yet, there are no changes in what is delivered to the browser.

A number of conversations suggests that Tomcat caching be dealt with. I would have to wonder why, during app development, this is an actual consideration.

But caching does not explain why **every** page and page resource request is served the same unchanging content.

What common mistake would a new java web app developer be making with respect to the setup/configuration of Tomcat and/or Eclipse and or the webapp that would explain this behavior?

Comment: Have you *looked* at the responses themselves in a web browser?

Comment: Yes. Using Firefox's Firebug, I can see the code that is received for each GET request.

Comment: ...are you going to share that with us? Why is it code for the images?

Comment: Share? The code received by the browser for each every GET request? To what end? I assure you it is the content for index.html for every GET request.

Comment: Do you have any kind of URI mapping set up in the web.xml or servlet classes?

Comment: URI mapping -- I assume you mean `<servlet-mapping>` in web.xml. So, yes. I also have annotations in the servlet.